# How to call stored procedure in background?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have one Stored Procedure which takes around 2-3 minutes to complete its execution. From ado.net i want to make that stored procedure execution happens in background.I have to return to my code as soon as i make the request to the stored procedure. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming :)  One important thing to know is the actual functionality of this stored procedure.  Does it really _need_ to happen inline in the user interface?  What is it doing?  By thinking about this, you can think about how to off-load it to another thread or another process entirely.  The user interface itself should definitely not have to wait that long.

Comment: Have you considered that the proc itself probaly needs performance tuning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should investigate [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx). In short you create a thread with the call to the stored procedure. When you start the thread it runs in the beackground. This thread can have a callback function that is called when the thread finishes.

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is an easy way to create threads.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a worker thread to execute the sproc call on a background call. Do you want to know the result of the sproc call? If you do then you will need to wait and join on the worker thread that is executing your sproc call. If not, you can just "fire and forget" - but you may not know about any errors / exceptions in this case.

[Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx) is an excellent post by Joe Albahari one threading.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Reactive programming (Rx)

The Rx is the new Microsoft proposal for simplifying asynchronous calls among other cool features

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

The Nuget package is:

https://nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/1.0.11226

It would be something like this:

```
    // here call the sp
    var o = Observable.Start(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });

    o.Subscribe(x => { Console.WriteLine("Operation done"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two options.  As others have mentioned, a very reasonable solution is to do threading in the application layer.  One thread launches the stored procedure and waits for the return.

The other is to do something similar in the database.  SQL Server, for instance, offers something called asynchronous queues.  You can send code to a query, which then gets picked up by a queue reader and runs in the background.

In your case, threading in the application is probably a fine solution.  I just wanted to bring the queuing idea to your attention, in case you anticipate that the workload of one stored procedure might become many, and you don't want to manage all the threads in your application.