# Entity framework async cancelling

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is related to my previous question:

[Async methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825574/async-methods-in-c-sharp/10825606#10825606)

As a recap I have several operations that take too much time to complete, therefore I wanted to run them asynchronously

Now I have all my operations running asynchronously and reporting the time each one takes to complete, also I added the cancellation but... even when the operation is cancelled in memory, the database operation appears to be still running =(((

The operations being executed in the database (SQL Server 2008) are stored procedures that basically connect with a linked database to perform a sync between the two databases

So basically how can I cancel this call to the sp's to stop the operation and rollback the transaction???

I am using EF to call the sp

Comment: Show some code how do you call the store procedure and how do you handle the context.